# No extensions appearing for gnome-shell 3.11.2

Tags: gnome, 13.10

I've been upgraded to gnome-shell 3.11.2 for several weeks now but have been unable to install any extensions through the gnome extensions website. I usually wait several days for the extensions devs to update the extensions to the newest gnome shell, but I have been unable to even view any extensions for a few weeks now. When I go to the gnome extensions website I cannot view any extensions unless I change the filter from "extensions for  your version" to "extensions for other versions".

Is this an issue with my gnome installation or are the extensions to being updated?

I am on 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your just using an outdated version this is 'bleeding edge' so it not hard to believe. Keep in Mind I did Zero research before answering this was just my first thought, also I'm a month late finding this and I just learned of Gnome 3.11 last night